# Simple Game in C# with only native libraries

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, game-loop, c#-native-library

I could find a set of [java 2D game tutorials](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/) and [android game tutorials](http://obviam.net/index.php/table-of-contents/) which uses ***only native graphics libraries***.
I'm looking for something similar in C# ( without DirectX or XNA)
I found [this game loop skeleton](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/99860-creating-games-in-c#-part-i/) , but it doesn't tell how to Render the Graphics.
Target is to simulate a simple Electronic device.
I need to show some graphical output as user "presses" some keys on the keyboard quickly.Hence it looks like an arcade game.
*For example* As the user presses one of the arrow keys a pointer(an image) will move accordingly.
I guess I can't do this with typical Windows Forms Application can I?
For example use a `PictureBox` control and move it in `KeyPress` event of the `Form`.

Comment: There's no reason why you can't do this with WinForms, though it wouldn't necessarily be very quick.

Comment: Winforms and a timer would be a very simple way of doing things.

Comment: Like Can I handle "5 key presses" per second?And would usage of PictureBox be ok?

Comment: Would OpenTK be native enough?

Comment: To render graphics you could use a picturebox. I'd create a Bitmap, and draw to that using Graphics.FromImage(backbuffer), then handle the Paint event of the picturebox and draw the backbuffer on. In the timer, invalidate the picturebox so it gets re-drawn once something changes.

Comment: And what about the WPF Canvas?

Comment: @Marnix thanks for WPF Canvas.I better use it

Comment: WinForms doesn't know anything about rendering - the technology you're looking for is GDI+ - I'm sure there are many many tutorials on google on how to draw using GDI+ :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a simple game using `WinForms` and a [`Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx), using [`Graphics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx) to draw (encapsulates GDI+).

It adds a timer that 'ticks' every 10 milliseconds. Each tick it performs game logic, then draws to an off screen bitmap. This is as opposed to using a continual loop as in the example in the link.

The form handles key events separately (as opposed to doing something like [`GetKeyState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

When the form is resized, and when it first loads it'll create the backbuffer bitmap of the right size.

---

Create a new form and replace all code with below. Control the ball using arrow keys. There's no notion of dying.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsGame
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Bitmap Backbuffer;

        const int BallAxisSpeed = 2;

        Point BallPos = new Point(30, 30);
        Point BallSpeed = new Point(BallAxisSpeed, BallAxisSpeed);
        const int BallSize = 50;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.SetStyle(
            ControlStyles.UserPaint |
            ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
            ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);

            Timer GameTimer = new Timer();
            GameTimer.Interval = 10;
            GameTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(GameTimer_Tick);
            GameTimer.Start();

            this.ResizeEnd += new EventHandler(Form1_CreateBackBuffer);
            this.Load += new EventHandler(Form1_CreateBackBuffer);
            this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Form1_Paint);

            this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);
        }

        void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
                BallSpeed.X = -BallAxisSpeed;
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
                BallSpeed.X = BallAxisSpeed;
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
                BallSpeed.Y = -BallAxisSpeed; // Y axis is downwards so -ve is up.
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
                BallSpeed.Y = BallAxisSpeed;
        }

        void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Backbuffer != null)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(Backbuffer, Point.Empty);
            }
        }

        void Form1_CreateBackBuffer(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Backbuffer != null)
                Backbuffer.Dispose();

            Backbuffer = new Bitmap(ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height);
        }

        void Draw()
        {
            if (Backbuffer != null)
            {
                using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(Backbuffer))
                {
                    g.Clear(Color.White);
                    g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, BallPos.X - BallSize / 2, BallPos.Y - BallSize / 2, BallSize, BallSize);
                }

                Invalidate();
            }
        }

        void GameTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BallPos.X += BallSpeed.X;
            BallPos.Y += BallSpeed.Y;


            Draw();

            // TODO: Add the notion of dying (disable the timer and show a message box or something)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks.I was confused with the comments and wonder which way to go.And I was going to keep the project itself aside and struggle with new stuff

Comment: I implemented this code. The idea is nice, but the refresh rate is really awful, I can see the speed ball being redrawn which is just ugly from a users's perspective. I too am trying to achieve a demo 2D game using plain c#  (without DirectX or XNA) for education purpose. Still digging so far

Comment: I solved it by adding Double buffering to the Form, using "DoubleBuffered = true"

Comment: @MehdiLAMRANI Interesting, the `SetStyle` lines should have the same effect as adding `DoubleBuffered = true`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make dynamic drawings, you can use the [WPF Canvas](http://www.wpftutorial.net/Canvas.html) for these purposes. It doesn't support gaming or such, but it is a simple way of drawing primitive forms and images as you would do in a website.

Answer (score 1):

The native rendering framework for .NET winforms apps is [GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533798%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). There are many [tutorials online](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/GDI_.aspx) for drawing simple shapes/graphics using GDI+