# Graphics save / restore state doesn't work

Tags: c#, graphics, gdi+, draw, picturebox

I have a simple code in which I can't figure out how to load previous Graphics state on pictureBox, there are two buttons to save (button1) and load (button2) state and a pictureBox.

```
    public Graphics g;
    public System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsState aState;

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        this.g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        this.g.FillEllipse(brush, e.X, e.Y, 5, 5);
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }

    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.g.Restore(this.aState);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.aState = this.g.Save();
    }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: what happens when you click button 1 and 2? What are the values of this.g and this.aState?

Comment: This code does absolutely nothing.  Very hard to guess why you think something ought to happen.   Never cache a Graphics object, it just adds failure modes.  They are *very* cheap to create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are trying to store the image, not the State. The graphics State only stores [transforms in the Graphics object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.save(v=vs.110).aspx), not the current picture, but the translation or the changes in SmoothingMode.

So my guess is that you need to store the picture like this:

```
Graphics g;

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
    this.g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    this.g.FillEllipse(brush, e.X, e.Y, 5, 5);
    pictureBox1.Refresh();
}

private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);
    buffer = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
    bufferGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(buffer);
}

Image buffer;
Graphics bufferGraphics;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bufferGraphics.DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image,0,0);
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
    this.g.DrawImage(this.buffer, 0, 0);
    pictureBox1.Refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code, you're not doing anything too crazy -- is there anyway you could just draw to a BackBuffer?  Normally, when I write something like this, I create a Bitmap that is in the class, say, _backBuffer.  All changes I make via the Graphics are ON this _backBuffer -- and then I render the _backBuffer onto the PictureBox.

So the flow looks something like...

MouseMove -- draw the details on the _backBuffer; call Invalidate() on pictureBox1.
pictureBox1 has a custom paint override that will render the _backBuffer onto itself.

At this point, you should be mostly OK -- things are drawing.  But, you'll want to save it, yes?

So you'll need to create one more Bitmap -- call it _savedBitmap.  When you click Button1, you'll use a Graphics.FromImage (I believe) on the _savedBitmap and render _backBuffer to it.  Button2 will do the same -- but in reverse -- rendering _savedBitmap onto the _backBuffer instead.

Hope that helps!

EDIT: Here's a link that explains some of how that works:
[Simple Game in C# with only native libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834775/simple-game-in-c-sharp-with-only-native-libraries)